# GetRequiredService from within Configure

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, simple-injector, tus

I'm trying to access one of my services from within the Configure call within Startup.cs in aspnet core. I'm doing the following however I get the following error "No service for type 'UserService' has been registered." Now I know it is registered because I can use it in a controller so I'm just doing something wrong when it comes to using it here. Please can someone point me in the right direction. I'm happy with taking a different approach to setting up Tus if there's a better way of achieving what I want.

```
      var userService = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<UserService>();
      userService.UpdateProfileImage(file.Id);
```

The below is where I'm wanting to use

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{

... Other stuff here...

  app.InitializeSimpleInjector(container, Configuration);

  container.Verify();


  app.UseTus(httpContext =>
  {

    var restaurantEndpoint = "/restaurant/images";
    var userEndpoint = "/account/images";
    var endPoint = "/blank/images";

    if (httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString(restaurantEndpoint)))
    {
      endPoint = restaurantEndpoint;
    }

    if (httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString(userEndpoint)))
    {
      endPoint = userEndpoint;
    }

    return new BranchTusConfiguration
    {
      Store = new TusDiskStore(@"C:\tusfiles\"),
      UrlPath = endPoint,
      Events = new Events
      {
        OnBeforeCreateAsync = ctx =>
        {
          return Task.CompletedTask;
        },

        OnCreateCompleteAsync = ctx =>
        {
          return Task.CompletedTask;
        },

        OnFileCompleteAsync = async ctx =>
        {
          var file = await ( (ITusReadableStore)ctx.Store ).GetFileAsync(ctx.FileId, ctx.CancellationToken);

          var userService = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<UserService>();
          userService.UpdateProfileImage(file.Id);
        }
      }
    };

  });

... More stuff here...

};
```

My end goal is to move this to an IApplicationBuilder extension to clean up my startup.cs but that shouldn't affect anything if it's working from within startup.cs

Edit: Add to show the registration of the userService. There is a whole lot of other stuff being registered and cross wired in the InitializeSimpleInjector method which I've left out. can add it all if need be..

```
 public static void InitializeSimpleInjector(this IApplicationBuilder app, Container container, IConfigurationRoot configuration)
{

  // Add application presentation components:
  container.RegisterMvcControllers(app);
  container.RegisterMvcViewComponents(app);

  container.Register<UserService>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

  container.CrossWire<IServiceProvider>(app);
  container.Register<IServiceCollection, ServiceCollection>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
}
```

Comment: "I know it is registered." Please show that registration.

Comment: Two different service providers. use the services from the httpcontext `httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserService>()` assuming that it was actually added in `ConfigureServices`

Comment: @Steven Added code showing registration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [Simple Injector integration page for ASP.NET Core](https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore) very closely, as Simple Injector integrates very differently with ASP.NET Core as Microsoft documented how DI Containers should integrate. The Simple Injector documentation states:

> Please note that when integrating Simple Injector in ASP.NET Core, you do not replace ASP.NET’s built-in container, as advised by the Microsoft documentation. The practice with Simple Injector is to use Simple Injector to build up object graphs of your application components and let the built-in container build framework and third-party components

What this means is that, since the built-in container is still in place, resolving components using `app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<T>()`—while they are registered in Simple Injector—will not work. In that case you are asking the built-in container and it doesn't know about the existence of those registrations.

Instead, you should resolve your type(s) using Simple Injector:

```
container.GetInstance<UserService>()
```